# 7 day weather forecast api

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am making a weather app and need 7 day forecast. I have successfully parsed and implemented google weather api XML in my app but the problem is that Google Weather API returns the forecast information of four days including the current day. For example, if today were Saturday, Google Weather API would return the forecast information of today (Saturday), Sunday, Monday, and Tuesday.

Can I make google api return 7 day forecast? If not then is there another weather api that I can use to get that info? Please keep in mind this app is going to be sold globally so I need something that can forecast a user weather for 7 days no matter where in the world they are.

The reason I went with google is that bloody company is reliable and the chances of their servers going down are minimal.

Comment: Perhaps this question has a workable answer for you?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4876800/is-there-an-international-weather-forecast-api-that-is-not-limited-for-non-comme

Comment: I went on that post and the weather apis there have limitations for free users. Unfortunately I am not a $$ iphone developer. Some don't allow more than 500 calls to their servers a day for free users. Even in this day and age there is no one reliable weather api. Geez, long live google, as much restrictive it maybe.

Comment: "Even in this day and age there is no one reliable weather api." Yes, there are many, but you need to pay for them.

Comment: Could you please tell me how you parsed and implemented google weather api XML, I really need it to work :(

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this one, it isn't free but doesn't seem to be very expensive.

http://www.worldweatheronline.com/

Comment: free accounts are limited to 500 requests per hour and price quote for montly/yearly premiums are hidden i.e. gotta contact them to get a quote. There are tons of other restrictions for free users. I'll pass on this one.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this one, but I'm not sure if it's global

http://graphical.weather.gov/xml/#xml_changes